# How do I turn off a function using jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have two buttons (on and off). When I click "on," I want to turn on the function called `turnToolOn`, and when I click "off," I want to turn off the function. I have this now:

```
$("body").on("click", "#turnOn", turnToolOn);
$("body").off("click", "#turnOff", turnToolOn);
```

The on() function is working, but I can't seem to get my function to stop executing when I click "off."

Comment: You're mixing double and single quotes in those code snippets, and are missing one in the second line; is this your actual code? If not, why didn't you post that?

Comment: Either you're not executing the turnToolOff function, or it isn't doing what you think it does. And, you haven't provided it.

Comment: Why are you passing a different selector on the .off?

Comment: uhm.... `$("body").off("click", "#turnOff", turnToolOn);` i don't think that does what you think it does?

Comment: Sorry, fixed! I don't have a turnToolOff function, but I just want to turn off the turnToolOn function.

Comment: I think you're missing a fundamental step here, *"understanding what .on and .off does"*. Without knowing what `turnToolOn` does and exactly how you want to turn it off, we aren't going to be able to answer you.

Comment: what does the turnToolOn function do??

Comment: turnToolOn turns my chrome extension tool on and it allows the user to execute drag events on the page. I want the user to be able to turn it off because drag is pretty sensitive.

Comment: Right, but unbinding the click event isn't going to turn it off. It's just going to make the click not turn it back on. *(hint: `.on` binds a click event, and .off unbinds it. `.off` does not turn off any functionality, it simply unbinds an event.)*

Answer (score 1):

You need to wrap your on/off events in a "click" event, and use the ID of the actual element you're using as the button to activate it.

So, if you have a button `<button id="turnOn">On</button>` and `<button id="turnOff">Off</button>`:

```
$( "#turnOn" ).click(function() {
  $( "body" )
    .on( "click", turnToolOn )
});
$( "#turnOff" ).click(function() {
  $( "body" )
    .off( "click", turnToolOn )
});
```

Read more at the [jQuery API Docs site for the off() event handler](http://api.jquery.com/off/#entry-examples)!

Answer (score 0):

As said in the comments, the calls you have only enable/disable certain event listeners in the DOM. If you need functions that start/stop something, you need to define them. Assuming that `turnToolOn` does what you expect it to do, you need to write its "counter" function (say `turnToolOff`) and use that as a handler attached to your off button:

```
$("body").on("click", "#turnOn", turnToolOn);
$("body").on("click", "#turnOff", turnToolOff); /// <--- here it is
```

And if you don't plan to remove/add on/off buttons dynamically (you can't have more than one anyway since you're using IDs), you can drop the delegated event handler (`on()`) and use regular binding after the DOM is ready.

Here is a super simple example that uses this to toggle a class of an element:

```js
$("body").on("click", "#turnOn", turnToolOn);
$("body").on("click", "#turnOff", turnToolOff);

function turnToolOn() {
  $('#el').addClass('on');
  }

function turnToolOff() {
  $('#el').removeClass('on');
  }
```

```css
#el {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background: #eee;
  }

#el.on {
  background: #0c0;
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button id="turnOn">On</button><button id="turnOff">Off</button>
<br />
<div id="el"></div>
```

And here is what on/off functions can do (binding/unbinding event handlers), so you can understand it better:

```js
$("body").on("click", "#turnOn", turnToolOn);
$("body").on("click", "#turnOff", turnToolOff);

function turnToolOn() {
  $("body").on("click", "#trigger", triggerCall);
  alert('trigger handler attached');
  }

function turnToolOff() {
  $("body").off("click", "#trigger", triggerCall);
  alert('trigger handler detached');
  }

function triggerCall() {
  $('#el').toggleClass('on');
  }
```

```css
#el {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background: #eee;
  }

#el.on {
  background: #0c0;
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button id="turnOn">On</button><button id="turnOff">Off</button>
<button id="trigger">Trigger</button>
<br />
<div id="el"></div>
```